# Как переносить данные из поля модального окна в QLineEdit?

Tags: c++, qt

Есть модальное окно, у которого в поле лежит объект другого класса:

```
class ParametersWindow : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    //  Поле, хранящее актуальные настройки
    ActualSettings settings;

    //  Конструкторы класса
    explicit ParametersWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ParametersWindow(ActualSettings &_settings, QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    // Деструктор класса
    ~ParametersWindow();

private slots:
    //  Нажатие на кнопку Загрузить
    void on_download_button_clicked();
    //  Нажатие на кнопку Отмена
    void on_cancel_button_clicked();
    //  Нажатие на кнопку Сохранить
    void on_save_button_clicked();

    void on_toDefault_button_clicked();

private:
    Ui::ParametersWindow *ui;
};
```

Класс ActualSettings:

```
class ActualSettings {

private:
    // Управление скоростью
    bool velocityControl;

    //  Ручной ввод номинальных моментов прибытия
    bool manualInput;

    // Номинальные значения прибытия ВС
    vector<double> nominalTimes;

    // Зерно разгона ДСЧ
    int randomSeed;

    // Количество потоков
    int flowQuantity;

    // Tбез для каждого потока
    vector<double> tauSafeFlow;

    // Количество обрабатываемых судов
    int aircraftsQuantity;

    // Tбез слитой очереди
    double tauSafe;

    // Правая граница временного интервала для разброса у первого ВС
    double rightBorderFst;

    // Правая граница временного интервала для разброса у последующих ВС
    double rightBorderNext;

    // Максимальная величина времени для ускорения ВС
    double maxAccelerationValue;

    // Максимальная величина задержки ВС
    double maxDelayValue;

    //  Копирование массивов
    void vecCopy(vector<double> &_fst, vector<double> &_snd);

    //  Сохранение в новый файл
    bool newFileOutput;

public:
    //  Конструкторы класса
    ActualSettings();
    ActualSettings(bool _velocityControl, bool _manualInput, vector<double> &_nominalTimes,
                   int _randomSeed, int _flowQuantity, vector<double> &_tauSafeFlow,
                   int _aircraftQuantity, double _tauSafe, double _rightBorderFst, double _rightBorderNext,
                   double _maxAccelerationValue, double _maxDelayValue, bool _newFileOutput);

    //  Деструктор класса
    ~ActualSettings();

    //  Установка значений по умолчанию
    void setToDefault();

    //  Переопределение оператора =
    ActualSettings& operator = (ActualSettings &_arg);
};
```

Хочу, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку в главном окне, открывалось моё модальное окно с уже заполненными QlineEdit. Надо как-то связывать готовыми методами или же это делается руками в конструкторе модального окна?

Comment: вы хотите заполнить `QLineEdit` текстом? Для этого у ного есть слот `setText`

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, да, текстом. Я уже попробовал в конструкторе окна это сделать, но ничего не отображается: //  Конструктор класса
ParametersWindow::ParametersWindow(ActualSettings &_settings, QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ParametersWindow)
{
   ui->setupUi(this);
   this->settings = _settings;
   ui->seed_line->setText(static_cast<QString>(settings.randomSeed));
}

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, как вообще сливать значения из текстовых полей в переменные, которые потом будут эти данные использовать? Там вроде какой-то метод connect есть, это оно?

Comment: чего? вы не в курсе что такое `connect`?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Ну, он связывает сигнал с нужным слотом

Comment: ну да, все верно, так в чем тогда вопрос?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, непонятно, куда это вколачивать. Если с переносом обратно в поле Класса понятно (кнопка сохранить нажата -> переносим в структуру), то появление после открытия окна — неочевидно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему через обычный setText():

```
ui->seed_line->setText(QString::number(settings.randomSeed));
```

Предыдущий вариант не работал из-за использования static_cast. static_cast не преобразовывает объект:

```
ui->seed_line->setText(static_cast<QString>(settings.randomSeed));
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто через конструктор передать значение. Для интерактивности можно  использовать [QDataWidgetMapper](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simplewidgetmapper-example.html) (модифицировать модель в обе стороны).

Comment: простите, можно подробнее, не совсем понятно, как реализовать. Только начинаю QT ковырять

Comment: Это часть [Qt Model-View Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html). Если у вас некоторое состояние задается моделью, то с помощью маппера можно "связать" с виджетом некоторое ее поле. То есть изменение поля будет тут же отображаться в модель и наоборот.